# Why vectorSource.clear() causes feature reload?

Tags: openlayers-3

I have `ol.source.Vector` with custom feature-loader. I need to completely replace existing features with new ones. So this is code inside loader:

```
vectorSource.clear();
vectorSource.addFeatures(features);
```

The problem is that calling `.clear()` causes the new feature loading and infinite loop as result. `load->clear->load->clear...`

Is this normal behavior? How can I clear features before add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tend to think this is the normal behavior. To avoid infinite loop you should call `vectorSource.clear()` from outside your `loader` and let it know that `vectorSource` was emptied. You will then change some parameter on `loader` function.

Since you didn't show code enough, I'll suggest something like:

```
var cleared = false;
vectorSource.on('clear', function(evt){
    cleared = true;
});
```

And inside loader function:

```
loader: function(){

    if(cleared) {
        //some logic
    }
```